# Photoshop layer comps and canvas height

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have a workflow issue. I create a homepage design in Photoshop and save out a layer comp. When I make secondary page layer comp it's invariably shorter. Obviously I can't crop to size, so I export out that layer comp then have to crop the jpeg. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, could you add some screenshots or explain further?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken you simply can't have different layer comps where the **canvas** changes size.

That's because layer combs affect layers, not the canvas (document).

I suppose a work-around could be (I tried it in CS6) :

- Select Layer Comb you want exported (secondary page layer comp)
- File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files ...
- You can choose (when selecting PNG) **TRIM LAYERS** . Which means that transparent space in the canvas will be removed. If your second homepage is smaller than the first design, it means that it's not using the whole canvas, so if you adjust the background color and leave what you don't want to show up as **transparent** you could have this script crop it out for you automagically.
- I imagine merging the layers you want to show up, before running the script, makes it more accurate when it comes to trimming the transparent space. In order not to lose the layers, as you click on "Merge Down/Merge Visible" hold **Alt** (in Windows, don't have a MAC to check what key combination is used in there) and it will create a new layer with the merged result. Make the other layers not visible, and run the script.

[image]

Hope it helps.